# Change variable group name dynamically in azure devops using a variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to change the variable group name in azure devops pipeline using the code below. I have tried different expressions `${{ variables.env}}`, `$(env)`, `$[eq(variables['env']`. None seem to work.

[image]

***build.yaml:***

```
variables:
- ${{ if eq('$(env)', 'Production') }}:
  - group: Production
- ${{ if eq('$(env)', 'Staging') }}:
  - group: Staging
- ${{ if eq('$(env)', 'Test') }}:
  - group: Test
- ${{ if eq('$(env)', 'Development') }}:
  - group: Development
```

Could you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: where are you defining the `env`? in pipeline variables?

Comment: Hi @Sibtain Yes, Pipeline variable.

Comment: Ok, but the question is why are you using pipeline variables and not runtime parameters?

Comment: Also you might want to share your complete YAML so we can get the context of why exactly you want to achieve this and what can be workaround

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75634485/3537880) answer, you don't need the conditions to evaluate the variable group. Below is a complete working YAML that uses `variables` instead of `parameters`

```
trigger: none
 
variables:
- name: env
  value: 'Staging'
- group: ${{ variables.env }}

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: Build
  steps:
  - script: echo Environment is $(env)
```

**Demo Run:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to determine proper variable group based on a value of variable defined for specific pipeline. The goal was to avoid the need to have separate yml file for each environment. First, I tried following syntax:

```
variables:
- ${{ if eq(variables['EnvName'], 'prod') }}:
  - group: prod
```

but `if` expression seems to be evaluated compile time and at that moment values of the variables are not yet set so it didn't work.

Instead I used one of the "[build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services)" which luckily are already set when `if` expression is processed. For me `DefinitionName` variable which returns the name of the build pipeline was a good candidate as I have environment specified in my pipelines' names:

[image]

This is what I used in the yml:

```
variables:
- ${{ if contains(variables['Build.DefinitionName'], 'testing') }}:
  - group: testing-env-group
- ${{ elseif contains(variables['Build.DefinitionName'], 'staging') }}:
  - group: staging-env-group
- ${{ elseif contains(variables['Build.DefinitionName'], 'production') }}:
  - group: prod-env-group
```